# Extracting data using datetime but getting a dtype error?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a set of data consisting of months, days, hours, and minutes. I want to extract the data from a .csv file and convert it into minutes using Python3. This is an example of the data set:

[image]

At the moment I am using pandas and datetime to do this but I am having a problem with the dtype when I try to extract the data for datetime. The error is:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

However, when I check the dtype of the data I am extracting, everything is an integer?

```
Year      int64
Month     int64
Day       int64
Hour      int64
Minute    int64
DHI       int64
DNI       int64
```

Here is my code:

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Open data file
data_file_name = "data_set.csv"
data_file = pd.read_csv(data_file_name, header=2).astype(int)

# Extract time data
print(data_file.dtypes)
dt = datetime.datetime(data_file["Year"], data_file["Month"], data_file["Day"], data_file["Hour"], data_file["Minute"])
delta = dt - datetime.datetime(data_file["Year"], 1, 1)
time_data = delta.total_seconds() // 60
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Datetime only can able to recognise string that in date time format. Your data inputs are in integer themselves so it cannot be converted. For the desirable outcome, I would recommend to concat all columns to one, and convert it to date-time format and apply the time delta function on that new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
date=pd.to_datetime(data_file[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']])
#get the date
delta=(pd.to_datetime(data_file['Year'].astype(str)+'-01-01')-date)
#get the time delta
time_data=delta.dt.total_seconds().div(60).abs()
#OR(Both are same so choose any one method)
time_data=delta.dt.total_seconds().abs() //60
#get the time_data
```

**Note:**

In the last 2 lines I use `abs()` function so that you get the minutes as positive number so If you want actual minutes remove the `abs()` function so last 2 steps becomes:

```
time_data=delta.dt.total_seconds().div(60)
#OR(Both are same so choose any one method)
time_data=delta.dt.total_seconds() //60
#get the time_data
```

Comment: anyone who downvoted....why downvote? Kindly tell!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
data_file['date'] = pd.to_datetime(str(data_file['year']) + str(data_file['month']) + str(data_file['day']))
```